When given the Fourier Series Expansion, what is the "DC Component" of the Electrical Signal?
I have come across 2 different ways to calculate the DC Term in Fourier Series for Electrical Signal $x(t)$ :
$$a_0 = \frac{2}{T}\int^T_0x(t)dt \tag{1}$$
And
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T}\int^T_0x(t)dt \tag{2}$$
I came across an article saying that the former is used for electrical engineering and the latter is used in cases not related to electrical engineering.
Since I come from an electrical engineering background, should I use the former?

Is the Fourier series written with an $a_{0}$ term or an $a_{0}/2$ term?

@BrianBorchers $a_{0}/2$

There are 2 Issues/Questions hiding in your Post.
(ISSUE 1)
There are at least 4 ways to calculate the Fourier Series terms & all ways are "Correct" when used consistently. I will list it for only the $a_0$ term :
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T}\int^T_0x(t)dt \tag{A}$$
$$a_0 = \frac{2}{T}\int^T_0x(t)dt \tag{B}$$
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T}\int^{+T/2}_{-T/2}x(t)dt \tag{C}$$
$$a_0 = \frac{2}{T}\int^{+T/2}_{-T/2}x(t)dt \tag{D}$$
MATHEMATICALLY IMPORTANT : the integration limit is in terms of $T$ , not $t$ , like in Question Post.
When we use (A) or (C) , then the Fourier Series for $x(t)$ will be in terms of $a_0$ & $2a_n \cos (\cdot)$ & $2b_n \sin (\cdot)$
When we use (B) or (D) , then all the terms ( including $a_0$ ) will be doubled & hence the Fourier Series for $x(t)$ will be in terms of $a_0/2$ & $a_n \cos (\cdot)$ & $b_n \sin (\cdot)$
Which-ever way we use , we should use it consistently though-out , otherwise we will be mixing Single terms with Double terms , leading to wrong answers.
(ISSUE 2)
Now that we have the "Correct" ways to get $a_0$ term , which is the DC term ?
The Question should be modified to : When given the Fourier Series Expansion , what is the "DC Component" of the Electrical Signal ?
We know that "DC Component" is the Non-Sinusoidal Constant term , which is the average over 1 Cycle.
In (B) & (D) , we have the Integration over 1 Cycle & Division by Period & Multiplication by 2 : Hence $a_0/2$ is the DC Component.
In (A) & (C) , we have the Integration over 1 Cycle & Division by Period & No Multiplication : Hence $a_0$ is the DC Component.
Electrical Engineers are advised to use (B) or (D) , because we automatically get the AC Component , while we have to make it $a_0/2$ for DC Component.

Issue 1 was an error on my side. Thanks for pointing that out
